# How to inject modules to main Angular app module on the fly

Tags: angularjs

I am not using angular on a single page application however I would like to define the main app module once due to load order issues. At the same time I would like to inject/require modules on a per page basis and not blanket as not all JS files will be loaded on every page.

Can I define the app with no required modules:

app = angular.module("app", [])

and have them injected from a controller or at a later stage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not officially supported at the moment. All the modules must be loaded in a browser (and declared as a dependency of a main application module) before AngularJS application is bootstrapped.

Comment: You said "at the moment". Will it be able in the future?

Comment: I though of something in the spur of the moment, posted in another answer, but would really like pkozlowski's input on it.

Answer (score 24):

Off the top of my head, upon reading your question, I can think of a possible solution/hack.

The idea would be to define an array of dependencies before any modules are included, and add to it within each module:

```
// before anything else
window.loadedDependencies = [];

// at the end of each module file:
window.loadedDependencies.push('moduleName')

// after all that, at the app definition:
app = angular.module("app", loadedDependencies)
```

In all honesty, I haven't really considered any implications/complications that this method may imply, and I can't really vouch for this until I do (why aren't fewer calls for script files and caching good for your use case?)

Comment: this is a great approach for a site consisting of multiple SPA-silos

Comment: this is actually a much better solution to what angular came with. it just seems awkward to load modules on every page for every other page. this way each page can define it's module dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

We can achieve it by using `app.requires`

```
//app.js
    var app = angular.module('myngapp',['ngRoute','ngCookies','ui.bootstrap','kendo.directives','pascalprecht.translate','tmh.dynamicLocale']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$translateProvider', 'tmhDynamicLocaleProvider', '$compileProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, tmhDynamicLocaleProvider, $compileProvider) {
    'use strict';

    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
    }]);
```

In myModule.js

```
  app.requires.push('app.myModule');
```

and in your index.html, include the `app.js` first and `myModule.js` next. By this way, you can include n number of modules without modifying the `app.js`.

Include the myModule.js on the fly from app.js

```
var mainHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
var myScript= document.createElement("script");
myScript.type = "text/javascript";
mainHead.appendChild( myScript);
myScript.src='../myModule.js';
myScript.onload = function(){
     angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myngapp']);
                     });
     }
```

Note: here we are manually bootstrapping the application so that dynamically loaded modules are also included into our application

Comment: Hey tk, can you please look into this question, i am following the method you described - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111131/dynamically-inject-angular-modules-as-dependency

Comment: Thanks! app.requires.push('moduleName'); worked perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

Using Tiago's great idea (upvote him!), I have the following in my module:

```
window.dependencies = _.union(window.dependencies || [], [
    "ngRoute",
    "app.mymodule1"
]);

angular
    .module("app.mymodule1", [])
    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        // more code
    }]);
```

and this in my `app.js`:

```
var app;

window.dependencies = _.union(window.dependencies || [], [
    "ngRoute",
    "app.anothermodule"
]);

window.app = app = angular.module("app", window.dependencies);
```

I use LoDash, so I [union](http://lodash.com/docs#union) the dependencies to get an array of unique values - some of my modules use the same dependencies as the `app.js`, e.g. `ngRoute`.

My script includes at the bottom of the `body` tag look like this:

```
<!-- scripts from other pages/modules included here -->

<script src="/js/anothermodule/anothermodule.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Works like a charm!

My pages share a "master" page, but I have the module definitions in their own files, so I needed something like this.

Comment: btw you don't need underscore to combine 2 arrays.. (window.dependecies || []).concat(['module1','module2'])

Comment: @SonicSoul arr.concat(arr1) will not merge them uniquely. it will include already included dependencies too. e.g.   var arr = ['a', 'b'], arr1 =['c', 'd', 'a'];  ----   arr.concat(arr1) --> will return ['a', 'b', 'c','d', 'a'].

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not very beautiful but what about doing the following:

```
var injectedDependencies = [.....];
angular.prevmodule = angular.module;
angular.module = function(name, params){
    if(params){
        params.push(injectedDependencies);
    }
    return angular.prevmodule.apply(angular, arguments);
}
```

edit: note that this is useful if you want to inject modules without the app having to know them (for exapmple for logging, monitorization, security, etc) but not if you want to inject'em after the application has been bootstraped.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same problem. 
I think http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/ may do what you wanted.

On its github https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad you can find:

1. that the only app which is injected is app https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/blob/master/examples/example1/index.html#L2
2. app is loading `AppCtrl.js` https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/blob/master/examples/example1/js/app.js#L24
3. `AppCtrl.js` later loads grid https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/blob/master/examples/example1/js/AppCtrl.js#L28 in runtime (and *asynchrously*)! **voi'la**

This might look a little complicated, but if you are really interested in loading them at runtime this might be the only one solution, except manually modyfing `_invokeQueue` manually.