# Dynamically inject angular modules as dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to inject angular module dynamically after some event as -

```
app.requires.push('projects');
console.log(app.requires);
```

I am referring to this link [How to inject modules to main Angular app module on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941069/how-to-inject-modules-to-main-angular-app-module-on-the-fly/37927950#37927950) to inject the module on occurrence of an event.

I have created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IFb8UT?p=preview) for the complete poc I have created. So on `app.requires` call it actually pushes `projects` module as dependency however when I click on link navigating to states defined inside the projects module, it logs an error stating `Could not resolve 'projects.login' from state ''`. Although these links work if I inject to module at the start only like `guides` module.

**PS:** Loading of project module happens upon clicking of button in index route.

Comment: `app.requires.push('projects')` will take effect if the app will be re-bootstrapped You can't add new modules to already bootstrapped app, Angular needs to be thoroughly patched to make this possible (something that ocLazyload does). It isn't clear why `loadScript2` in your example should be loaded dynamically, there is a good chance that you have XY problem.

Comment: Cool..thanks for mentioning re-bootstrapping of the app. I missed that part. its working fine now. Also problem is a bit different and I can't put complete code here. Anyways it is fixed and I will keep the plunkr alive for anyone visiting it in future.